# It is a good idea to implement a facade service between the controllers and services?

Tags: design-patterns, unit-of-work, entity-framework-ctp5

In the scenario where i am using an unit of work into each service class methods in order to do operations and application logic. It is a good idea to implement a facade service between the controllers and services ? The idea was to be able to use many services in one transaction without using more than one unit of work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its a good idea if

1) the services you all from the controllers themselves invoke other services, and it is getting to be unmanageable.
2) you are struggling with a situation where you need to call two services at a high level but are having trouble making it work design-wise

As kohlehydrat mentions, they are very useful with SOAs, but I disagree in that a Facade is  a design pattern -- it isn't exclusive to anyone application style. If you use a facade, you end up with one, well organized high level service for your application (if you do it right).

Comment: The unit of work is to be used only once per request plus i prefer the SOA approach to any other approach because i end up to be more flexible. I need to be able to call one or more services in my server layer and reuse service methods in some place within the same transaction. So i suppose from what you said that i actually need one right ?

Comment: you don't *need* one.  Its just a pattern that presents a unified interface for the application.  I think its simpler.  I dont know how your framework works, but in the Java world you can configure the transaction boundaries on your services -- so that way, if serviceA has a transaction around a method, and it calls other services, the same transaction is used throughout.

Comment: Alright i think your right actually. If i ever reuse a method inside my service layer i just have to make it not use an uow and make it private. Btw i was using asp.net mvc 3. My uow are defined through an using statement.

Answer (score 0):

No, the facade pattern makes only real sense in the context of SOAs. You should try a more service-oriented approach to fit your needs.

Comment: I don't think i am referring to the facade pattern as hvgotcoddes said i don't think this can be called a pattern.